# Using PowerShell as VIM shell

Tags: powershell, vim

I'm using the console version of VIM (not gvim) in Windows, and I have a question about using PowerShell as the shell.

I have set my shell to be powershell and I can run commands, but there's one thing I don't know. I have a bunch of things going on in my PowerShell profile, and I was wondering if it's possible to somehow pass something to PowerShell using VIM, so that in the profile I can check and decide what to do.

I know there's an option **-NoProfile** we can pass to *powershell.exe*, but my problem is that I don't want to ignore my whole profile, because I need some parts, such as aliases etc.

Thanks,

Comment: Write a custom profile script that sets `$fromVim` variable and then sources the normal profile? Check the environment when run from vim and see if it differs reliably from the environment when run by explorer/etc.?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I set this environment variable from inside VIM? I mean, I should have a way to set this variable so that when I run a shell command like **:!<command>**, I can do the checking stuff? Because I looked at **powershell.exe** options, and there's no option to pass a custom profile to it

Comment: Pass a command that sets a variable to Powershell on the command line: powershell -command "$global:fromVim = $true"

Comment: I didn't suggest setting it inside vim, though you might be able to, I suggested using a powershell profile script specially written to set it and then call the *normal* powershell profile script that then does the checking/etc. That way normal powershell doesn't have it set and only vim powershell does. There might be a better way to do this (and probably is) but that would work.

Comment: Actually, when I try to set **set shell=powershell.exe ... -command "& {...}"** and then I try to call something, for example, **:!ls**, it says *The term -c is not recognized as a cmdlet etc.*

Comment: @EtanReisner, so, if I create that specific profile, how do I make sure I call it when calling a command from vim; I don't see any options for passing a profile to **powershell** command

Comment: `set shell=powershell.exe\ -file\ path_to_file.ps1`? I'm not actually sure. You might want a `PSConsoleFile` instead or something with `-command`. You'd have to try it and see.

Comment: @EtanReisner The problem with using **-File** option is that it then ignores whatever command I send using **:!<command>** syntax. It just runs the file. Also, **-Command** has the problem I mentioned above. I'm not sure what the **PSConsoleFile** does however and how I can use it